# SQLServer DATETIME conversion to STRING if NULL

Tags: sql-server

my datetime column (type=datetime) in my DB is as follows

[image]

why is this statement not converting the '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' values to 'date not set'

```
ISNULL(
   CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, [TB].Date) = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
   THEN 'date not set' 
   ELSE CONVERT(DATE, [TB].Date, 25) 
   END, '') AS Xdate,
```

What am i missing?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Slightly OT so I'll post this as a comment rather than an answer: Since "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000" is the baseline value for the `DATETIME` type, you could simplify to something like `CASE WHEN [TB_EVNTCERT].StartDate = 0 THEN ... ELSE ... END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try this code you will see that when you convert it to varchar it does not equal the string you are comparing it to:

```
declare @Startdate as datetime
set @Startdate='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'

select CONVERT(VARCHAR, @StartDate)
```

You want to compare the `datetime` types.  And you need to output the date as a `varchar` because you also want to output `'date not set'` which is not a date.  You can't conditionally output a different type... only one or the other can be the type of your case statement.

So you need to swap the date/varchar conversions in your expression:

```
ISNULL(
   CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, [TB_EVNTCERT].StartDate) = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN
       'date not set' 
   ELSE 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, [TB_EVNTCERT].StartDate, 25) 
   END, '') AS expirydate,
```

Answer (score 2):

Your CASE statement cannot work.   The result of the CASE statement must be a single datatype.  You are trying to return a varchar ("date not set") in one case, and a DATE in another case.

You must return the same datatype in all cases.